# how to make a container expand to fit text in a SingleChildScrollView flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want to make containers that have text in them the problem comes in the container where the text should fit according to the text

for example in one of the container i want to fit the description of the property and that is dynamic according to the user he/she can add few description or add a lot of description so i want the container to resize according to the text

Please advice the best way

```
    class _PropertyDetailScreenState extends State<PropertyDetailScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Image(
                height: 270.0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                image: AssetImage('assets/2.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 50),
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                        iconSize: 30.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                        iconSize: 30.0,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
            ]),
            Container(
              height: 90,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.purple,
                //border: new Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 5.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
              ),
              /*child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "15,000 Ksh/Month",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Sofia Pro',
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '20',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Sofia Pro',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.favorite,
                            color: Colors.red,
                            size: 20,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Mvita, Mombasa',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Sofia Pro',
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 3),
                  Text(
                    "3 Rooms",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Sofia Pro',
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),*/
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                child: Text(
                  'text texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                      'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                      'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                      'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                      'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                      'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'text texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                    'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                    'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                    'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                    'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                    'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'text texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                    'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                    'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                    'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                    'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
                    'texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 70),
            /*Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(12),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12))),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  //
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "15,000 Ksh/Month",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Sofia Pro',
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '20',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Sofia Pro',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.favorite,
                            color: Colors.red,
                            size: 20,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 3),
                  //
                  Text(
                    'Mvita, Mombasa',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Sofia Pro',
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 3),
                  //
                  Text(
                    "3 Rooms",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Sofia Pro',
                      fontSize: 12,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  //
                  Text(
                    "Amenities",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontFamily: 'Sofia Pro',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  /*Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        itemCount: widget.doc.data()['furnished'].length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)
                        {
                          return Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(Icons.check,size: 15,),
                                  SizedBox(width: 10,),
                                  Text(widget.doc.data()['furnished'][index]),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),*/
                  Text(
                    "Description",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontFamily: 'Sofia Pro',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 3,
                  ),
                  //
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      'This a description of the house This a description of the'
                          'house This a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the houseThis a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the houseThis a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the house This a description'
                          ' of the houseThis a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the houseThis a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the houseThis a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the houseThis a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the houseThis a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the houseThis a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the houseThis a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the houseThis a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the houseThis a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the houseThis a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house This a description of the house This a description '
                          'of the house',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),*/
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: Container(
        height: 65,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green, boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black45,
            offset: Offset(0, -1),
          ),
        ]),
        child: Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text('CONTACT',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 24.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    letterSpacing: 1.2)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at `FittedBox`

```
FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, 
        child: Text('texttextextext')
    ),
```

or even take a look at this [auto_size_text plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)

Comment: Try other fit values to see which one suits you the most
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: data.messages[data.messages.length-index-1].isOwn?Alignment.centerRight:Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Container(
                           constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: size.width*0.15, maxWidth: size.width*0.8),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(size.height/70),
                        color: data.messages[data.messages.length-index-1].isOwn?Colors.green:Colors.blueGrey
                      ),
                      
                     
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: size.width*0.01,bottom: size.height/70),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(size.height/70),
                                  child: Container(
                          
                        
                          child: RichText(text: TextSpan(
                            children: [
                            
                            
                              TextSpan(text:"${data.messages[data.messages.length-index-1].messagebody}",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: size.height/50),)
                              ,TextSpan(text: "    ${data.messages[data.messages.length-index-1].time}",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: size.height/90,),)
                            ]
                          ))
                          ),
                      )),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

You can use Expanded widget inside Row like this, I used this for messages in my Chat application
size.width and size.height is Size class that I used for making it responsive

Answer (score 0):

i have seen the problem when you want a container to fit child do not specify the height simply leave it out it will automatically adjust according to child size

```
        Container(
          //height: 90,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.purple,
            //border: new Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 5.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
          ),
```